# Where in the DB is the Location of a PostgreSQL tablespace stored

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, tablespace

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 on RedHat 6. I am looking for the database table and column which stores the location for a PostgreSQL tablespace. I thought it would be in PG_TABLESPACE, but

```
select * from pg_tablespace
```

shows...

```
postgres=# select * from pg_tablespace;
     spcname     | spcowner | spcacl | spcoptions
-----------------+----------+--------+------------
 pg_default      |       10 |        |
 pg_global       |       10 |        |
 C_TBL_DB91SABIR |       10 |        |
(3 rows)
```

but no location, any ideas where the location is kept?

Comment: Not the exact answer : `SHOW data_directory;` will show you the location of current DB

Comment: hi @wingedpanther, that shows the PGDATA location, but i'm looking for the directory of the tablespace, i want to query it so that i can script a removal of the physical folder when a tablespace is dropped.

Comment: Try this `select spcname, pg_tablespace_location(oid) from pg_tablespace;
`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`pg_tablespace_location(tablespace_oid)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)(PostgreSQL 9.2+) to get the path in the file system where the `tablespace` is located.

You'll get `oid` of `tablespace` from `pg_tablespace`, so the query should be

```
select spcname
      ,pg_tablespace_location(oid) 
from   pg_tablespace;
```

Comment: both this sql query and psql command \db+ is relevant with user defined or so called non system tablespaces. e.g default pgroot is defined by environment variable PGROOT on some cases

Answer (score 8):

Another super easy command to list all table spaces

> \db+

This will provide you all table space details very quick

Answer (score -6):

Use below query to get tablespace name tablespace location.

```
postgres=# select spcname ,pg_tablespace_location(oid) from pg_tablespace;
  spcname   |    pg_tablespace_location     
------------+-------------------------------
 pg_default | 
 pg_global  | 
 fastspace  | /var/lib/postgresql/data/base
 demotbs    | /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: What's the point in duplicating the already existing accepted answer?